# Can't type in UITextFiled when placed in UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

A button triggers a function that creates a UIActionSheet. Looks like this:

```
reportSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
               initWithTitle:nil
               delegate:self
               cancelButtonTitle:nil 
               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
               otherButtonTitles:nil
               ];

[reportSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

When i add a UITextField to this ActionSheet, I cant type any thing in it. The keyboard appears but when I press the buttons nothing happens. The marker just stands in position 0 and blink. 
This code looks like this:

```
newComment = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200)];
newComment.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
newComment.delegate = self;
[reportSheet addSubview:newComment];
[newComment release];
```

If I add the TextField to self.view (instead of reportSheet above) it works fine and there's no problem to type in it.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: You might have a look @ [iPhone UIActionSheet with UISwitch and UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654091/iphone-uiactionsheet-with-uiswitch-and-uitextfield) and [how to enable text input in UITextField which is in UIActionSheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089437/how-to-enable-text-input-in-uitextfield-which-is-in-uiactionsheet)

Comment: I think there is a problem with the frame size of `UITextField`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
[newComment.layer addAnimation:[reportSheet.layer animationForKey:reportSheet.layer.animationKeys.lastObject] forKey:reportSheet.layer.animationKeys.lastObject];
 [[reportSheet superview] addSubview:newComment];
```